# Im trying to use time in python as a trigger for a comand

Tags: python, datetime, time, while-loop

im trying to make a command happen when its a certain time but its not working someone please help thanks,
here is my code

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

while True:

    sam = (datetime.now().time())
    ssam = str(sam)

    if ssam == ('23:12:24.092411'):
        print("hui")


    else:
       pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The odds of calling `datetime.now().time()` at a precise *microsecond* are slim. One-second accuracy would probably be sufficient, and if so, you don't want to call `datetime.now().time()` as fast as you can; even a one-second delay in the loop saves thousands of unnecessary calls.

```
import datetime
import time

at_time = datetime.time(23, 14, 12)

while datetime.datetime.now().time() < at_time:
    time.sleep(1)

print("hui")
```

Comment: while datetime.now().time() < at_time:
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Fixed; I was only importing the module, not the class from the module, and forgot to adjust the call to `now` appropriately.